# PHP Error 500 with Google

Tags: php, internal-server-error, googlebot

Google recently detected a 500 internal server error on our site homepage. When I use "fetch as Google" this is what I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: private
Pragma: private
Content-Encoding: gzip
Set-Cookie: bb_lastvisit=1385209760; expires=Sun, 23-Nov-2014 12:29:20 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: bb_lastactivity=0; expires=Sun, 23-Nov-2014 12:29:20 GMT; path=/
Host-Header: 192fc2e7e50945beb8231a492d6a8024
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 7641
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Sat, 23 Nov 2013 12:29:21 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
X-Forwarded-For: 66.249.73.225
X-Cache: SGCACHE-MISS
```

and below this, the normal html for my site.
It happens only with Google, and only in the homepage, ALL other pages are crawled without any issues (visitors can display all site pages normally of course, including the homepage).

Everything is fine with the hosting server, no settings were changed.
php_errorlog reports the same rror over and over:

```
[22-Nov-2013 11:10:33 CST6CDT] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/chattive/public_html/forum.php(89) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

although our programmer said there is no issue.

I am desperate, what could it be?

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!!!

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the actual source code. But a `eval()` error on line 1 of your script seems very suspicious to me.

Comment: @MathieuImbertmI think that's line 1 of evaled code, and the eval is on line 89. But yeah, without the code we can hardly even guess...

Comment: @frnhr Thank you very much for your comments. You can view the code here if needed: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-mwqOK_AOMdVjU5UFc5aWxUeUk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please guys I really need your help, I don't know what to do...
Thanks in advance!